# Помогите улучшить код написанный на java

Tags: java

есть структуры которых уже больше 2 десятков. помогите улучшить код. а именно какой код можно объединить в этих 2 структурах (остальные структуры похожи на эти)

class Structure_FBX_Document

```
private Structure_FBX_Header_Extension fbx_header_extension;
private String file_Id;
private Structure_Date creationTime;
private String creator;
private Structure_FBX_Global_Settings globalSettings;
private Structure_FBX_Documents documents;
private Structure_FBX_References references;
private Structure_FBX_Definitions definitions;
private Structure_FBX_Objects objects;
private Structure_FBX_Connections connections;
private Structure_FBX_Takes takes;

public FBX_Structure_Document(List<FBX_Node> nodes)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.size(); i++)
    {
        FBX_Node child = nodes.get(i);

        if (child.getName().equals("FBXHeaderExtension"))
            fbx_header_extension = new Structure_FBX_Header_Extension(child);
        else if (child.getName().equals("FileId"))
            file_Id = nodes.get(i).getProperty(0).toString();
        else if (child.getName().equals("CreationTime"))
            creationTime = new Structure_Date(child.getProperty(0));
        else if (child.getName().equals("Creator"))
            creator = nodes.get(i).getProperty(0).toString();
        else if (child.getName().equals("GlobalSettings"))
            globalSettings = new Structure_FBX_Global_Settings(child);
        else if (child.getName().equals("Documents"))
            documents = new Structure_FBX_Documents(child);
        else if (child.getName().equals("References"))
            references = new Structure_FBX_References(child);
        else if (child.getName().equals("Definitions"))
            definitions = new Structure_FBX_Definitions(child);
        else if (child.getName().equals("Objects"))
            objects = new Structure_FBX_Objects(child);
        else if (child.getName().equals("Connections"))
            connections = new Structure_FBX_Connections(child);
        else if (child.getName().equals("Takes"))
            takes = new Structure_FBX_Takes(child);
        else
        {
            try
            {
                throw new Exception("Тип не найден: " + child.getName());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
// ниже идут геттеры
```

class Structure_FBX_Definitions

```
private int version;
private int count;
private List<Structure_Object_Type> object_typeList = new ArrayList<Structure_Object_Type>();

public Structure_FBX_Definitions(FBX_Node node)
{
    super(node);

    for (int i = 0; i < node.getSize_Children(); i++)
    {
        FBX_Node child = node.getChild(i);
        if (child.getName().equals("Version")) version = Integer.parseInt(child.getProperty(0).toString());
        else if (child.getName().equals("Count")) count = Integer.parseInt(child.getProperty(0).toString());
        else if (child.getName().equals("ObjectType")) object_typeList.add(new Structure_Object_Type(child));
    }
}
// ниже идут геттеры
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По порядку:

**1.Называйте классы правильно!**

Для разделения слов в именах классов и переменных используют **CamelCase** или **snake_case** - у Вас и первое и второе.

Выберите что-то одно, пожалуйста.

Причём по отдельности Вы тоже их используете:

```
private Structure_Date creationTime;
```

Читать такую "кашу" очень непросто.

Кроме того в Java есть конвенции и имена классов принято именовать CamelCase'ом (так что выбора у Вас нет)

Дальше!

**2. Вы создаёте переменную и забываете её использовать**

Перед циклом вы создаёте переменную

```
FBX_Node child = nodes.get(i);
```

А потом дважды обращаетесь к той же ноде через  `nodes.get(i)`.

```
    else if (child.getName().equals("FileId"))
        file_Id = nodes.get(i).getProperty(0).toString();
    //...
    else if (child.getName().equals("Creator"))
        creator = nodes.get(i).getProperty(0).toString();
```

Не надо так.

Создал переменную - используй её!

Вы путаете читателя: в условие используете одну ссылку, в следствии-другую...поди догадайся что это одно и тоже в сотне ифов.

**3. Используйте switch!**

Серьёзно, это просто ужас...такого нагромождения кода я давно не видел...

не лучше ли Всё сделать так:

```
        switch (child.getName()){
            case "FBXHeaderExtension":
                fbxHeaderExtension = new StructureFBXHeaderExtension(child);
                break;
            case "FileId":
                fileId = child.getProperty(0).toString();
                break;
            case "CreationTime":
                creationTime = new StructureDate(child.getProperty(0));
                break;
            case "Creator":
                creator = child.getProperty(0).toString();
                break;
            case "GlobalSettings":
                globalSettings = new StructureFBXGlobalSettings(child);
                break;
            case "Documents":
                documents = new StructureFBXDocuments(child);
                break;
            case "References":
                references = new StructureFBXReferences(child);
                break;
            case "Definitions":
                definitions = new StructureFBXDefinitions(child);
                break;
            case "Objects":
                objects = new StructureFBXObjects(child);
                break;
            case "Connections":
                connections = new StructureFBXConnections(child);
                break;
            case "Takes":
                takes = new StructureFBXTakes(child);
                break;
            default:
                throw new TypeNotFoundException("Тип не найден: " + child.getName());
                break;
        }
```

Это конечно, тоже портянка та ещё, но тут можно быстро найти нужный участок кода и мгновенно понять что он делает, а в Вашем случае всё выглядит гораздо тяжелее.

Что со свитчем можно сделать мы ещё дальше разберёмся.

**4.Exception !**

Начнём с того, что Exception и без того спорная вещь и её наличие в Jav'е подвергается множеству нападок как со стороны, так и изнутри Java-коммюнити.

Но, если уж Вы и решились на использование исключений, то делайте это правильно.

**4.1 Тип исключения.**

Нет ничего хуже использования нетипизированного исключения!!!

Уровнем Выше Вы не сможете отличить `NullPointerException` от своего исключения. Вам придётся перехватывать все исключения подряд, а это *не есть хорошо*, т.к. Вы можете пропустить и проигнорировать реальные ошибки, считая их очередным пропущенным "типом".

Вернее будет создать класс `TypeNotFoundException` наследованный от `Exception` и выбросить уже его в кейсе. Тем самым Вы сможете легко опознать данную ошибку в любой точке своей программы, Вам не нужно будет перекрывать весь поток ошибок и не нужно будет их все перебирать. Более того в самом классе исключения Вы сможете вывести дополнительную информацию по ноде удобным Вам образом.

**4.2 Использование исключения и уровни управления.**

```
        try
        {
            throw new Exception("Тип не найден: " + child.getName());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Какой в этом смысл?

Смысл исключения в том, чтобы эскалировать проблему на ряд уровней выше, в то место программы, где данная проблема может быть решена. Предполагается, что в месте выброса исключения Вы не можете оценить серьёзность ошибки и предпринять какие-либо действия для её обработки. Самая распространённая ошибка - это перехват исключения раньше времени(по всей видимости из-за боязни ошибок), что приводит в итоге к непредвиденному поведению программы. Однако, в Вашем случае Вы просто не понимаете зачем их вообще использовать.

Вы выбрасываете исключение и тут же его ловите для того чтобы просто вывести, что Вы не обработали какой-либо тип.
Для начала Вы должны понять - является ли это для Вас исключительной ситуацией?

Если нет, то Вы могли с тем же успехом использовать `Log` или вообще `System.out.println("Тип не найден: " + child.getName());`

Если же да и в будущем, это будет исключительной ситацией и только на момент отладки Вы сразу же перехватили это исключение, то наилучшим решением будет сразу же перенести обработку данного исключения в то место, где Вы сможете решить, что с ним стоит делать.

**5. Общие пожелания**

Разберитесь с паттернами проектирования.

**MUST READ**:

- *Thinking in Java*
- *Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software*

Для того чтобы глубже понимать язык, на котором Вы программируете и проектирование объектно-ориентированных программ.

Также настоятельно советую к прочтению книгу "***Рефакторинг***" Мартина Фаулера, которая поможет применять полученные в вышеупомянутых книгах знания и поэтапно улучшать свой код, делая его читабельнее, красивее, удобнее, полезнее и т.д.

В частности Вам тут определённо может помочь один из ***Порождающих шаблонов*** или же ***Замена условного оператора полиморфизмом***, однако для более точного ответа маловато кода, чтобы подобрать вариант оптимальный в Вашем случае.

Comment: Спасибо за советы буду учитывать, а книги которые вы написали прочту. Можно ли с вами связаться по некоторым вопросам.

Comment: Можете написать в комментариях к данной записи или в чат http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59405/rmv Однако, сразу замечу что свободного времени у меня практически нет.